# Equivalent to Struts 1.x "bean:define" tag?

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, struts, jstl, javabeans

I'm working on converting an old Struts 1.x application to Spring MVC and in some of the JSP pages, the `bean:define` tag is being used to get a string from a resource bundle, and is then used later in the page:

```
<bean:define id="example_title"><fmt:message bundle="${example_Labels}" key="example_field"/></bean:define>
```

then later:

```
title="<%=example_title%>"
```

I'm not sure what the equivalent JSTL (or if it even should be JSTL) tag should be in order to do away with the Struts tag, can anyone offer a suggestion?  I've tried playing with JSTL `set`, and `jsp:useBean`, but either they're the wrong way to go or I'm implementing them improperly.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `var` attribute of the `fmt:message`.

```
<fmt:message bundle="${example_Labels}" key="example_field" var="example_title" />
```

This basically exports the value associated with the key into a page scoped variable named `example_title`. You can print it later in the page the usual EL way:

```
title="${example_title}"
```

Or if you're still on pre-JSP-2.0 where EL in template text isn't supported (consider upgrading..), then use `<c:out>` to display it:

```
title="<c:out value="${example_title}" />"
```

Comment: I tried this way: I don't get any JSP errors when testing but the value of the title is blank when the page renders.  It's almost like the var="example_title" doesn't get recognized.  

The project is pre-JSP-2.0, as it takes the "${example_title}" as a literal string value and uses it as the title.

Comment: Then it's probably not in the same scope. Are you displaying it in an include page (`jsp:include`)? If so, add a `scope="request"` to the `fmt:message`. The include page uses the same request.

Comment: Good thought, but it's within the same page.  Just in case I tried using scope = page/request/session/application with the same result.  Would it make a difference that the title= portion is within a <display:column> tag?  So I tried:  <display:column title="<c:out value='${example_title}' />">

Comment: You should use `<display:column title="${example_title}">` instead.

Comment: I'm assigning this as the correct answer.  It turns out there's some issue the <display:column> tag has with rendering the output either with ${example_title} or <c:out value='${example_title}'/>">  Otherwise this does work as it should.  If I can find a way around the <display:column> tag issue I'll post it here for others.  Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1):

You can access your defined bean using the ${} notation

```
<%
  title = ${example_title}
%>
```

If you want to print it, you could use the `<c:out>` tag

```
<c:out value=${example_title}/>
```

[Here's](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javaserverpages/faster/) a quick link on JSTL

Comment: EL doesn't work inside *scriptlet* and you forgot the quotes in c:out.