# Can I convert <bean:write> to EL in Struts?

Tags: jsp, struts, el

If I'm not mistaken, in Struts 1.3 these three expressions are equivalent:

```
<bean:write name="form" property="foo" />

<c:out value="${form.foo}" />

${form.foo}
```

**Are there any differences**? The only one I've found is that [`<c:out>` escapes XML output, and `${}` doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18309728/difference-between-cout-and-print-the-output-using). No idea about `<bean:write>`, it says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6692995/how-to-use-beanwrite-tag-in-strut-1-2) that it searches the `form` property in the page context, then in the request, then in the session... but I guess `<c:out>` and `${}` do that, too.

Now... **what would this expression do?**

```
<bean:write name="${form}" property"foo" />
```

My guess is that the `${form}` part gets evaluated first, then it finds wathever object was named in the `form` variable, and recovers its `foo` property. If that's in fact what it does... **can I convert it to an EL**? Something like this, but actually working:

```
${${form}.foo}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>Self answering the last question:</sub>

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241963/equivalent-to-struts-1-x-beandefine-tag) and [this](https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1142575), I believe that I could use `<bean:define>` in this way:

```
<bean:define id="blarg" name="${form}" property="foo" />
```

And then this would become available:

```
${blarg}
```

I still haven't tested it though.